# In elbow curve how to find the point from where the curve starts to rise?

Tags: outliers, threshold, curves

I am computing a distance on my data. The result is then being sorted in ascending order.
The samples having distance more than a specific threshold are to be marked as outliers and will be discarded. Below is a plot of all distance values.

[image: graph]

As evident from the graph, after a certain point, the graph rises quite rapidly and even the datapoints get sparse. I need to calculate that point from where this happens.

Comment: This is very unclear. My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](https://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you formulate a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually comes from a different field, from image processing and thresholding. However it can be used here as well.

The goal is to draw a straight line from the lowest to the highest point, moving along this line and searching for the perpendicular line with longest distance to the histogram / curve. See image below.

[image]

You didn't mention what software you will be using, in case you are using R you can do this by using the `autothresholdr` package.

**Edit:** there are different methods available going by the name Triangle, Huang, Intermodes, MaxEntropy, Otsu, and so on.

Comment: I am using python 3.7. Do you know the equivalent python package for `autothresholdr`

Comment: @FaizKidwai I do not, although there should exist something of the sort. Also I forgot to mention the name, I edited the answer.

Comment: @FaizKidwai have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213278/implementing-otsu-binarization-from-scratch-python

Comment: I ended up implementing this in python using `shapely.geometry`

Comment: This method unfortunately is arbitrary, because--depending on how one scales the two axes relative to each other--it can produce almost any answer.

Answer (score -1):

Rotate the curve by a certain angle (based on the axes scale) and then find the minimum value. [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/57122/in-elbow-curve-how-to-find-the-point-from-where-the-curve-starts-to-rise) answer best relates to this problem.